# php class to inherit only one method

Tags: php, oop, class, inheritance

I have these classes:

```
class User{
    private $user_ID;
    private $first_name;
    private $surname;
    ...

    private $website;
    private $company;

    function __construct($array){
        $this->user_ID            = $array["userId"];
        $this->first_name         = $array["first"];
        $this->surname            = $array["last"];
        $this->telephone          = $array["tele"];
        ...
    }
    public function addWebsite($array){
        $this->website = $array;
    }
    public function addCompany($array){
        $this->company = $array;
    }
    public function getData(){
        $array = array();
        foreach($this as $var => $value) {
            $array[$var] = $value;
        }
        return $array;
    }
}

class Website{
    private $webId;
    private $url;
    private $description;
    ...

    function __contruct($array){
        $this->webId           = $array["webId"];
        $this->url             = $array["url"];
        $this->description     = $array["desc"];
        ...
    }
}
```

the getData() method in User is exactly the same for the Website class.

so how can i get the website class to implement this method? But ONLY the getData() method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While inheritance forms an [*behaves-as* relationship](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), this is not a situation for Inheritance. Your `Website` is not related to the `User` in any way, so there shouldn't be a relationship between them.

Having [base classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BaseBean) like suggested elsewhere here will quickly lead to monolithic architecture and [god objects](http://sourcemaking.com/antipatterns/the-blob). Those in turn lead to [less maintainability, high coupling, fragile code and hampers reuse](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/oodmetrc.pdf). Likewise, making everything public or resorting to similar means that defeat information hiding and widen the public API lead to similar problems and you will want to avoid them.

What you are looking for is [`Traits`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php), but these are only supported as of PHP 5.4. The easiest approach is really just to duplicate that method in both classes. Keep in mind that you usually want to avoid code duplication, but in this case its the lesser evil over the other suggested alternatives.

A viable alternative would be to use an Introspection Service that uses Reflection to fetch the data from the object into an array. Although in general, [you should put methods on the objects having the data the methods operate on](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/GRASP_%28object-oriented_design%29#Information_Expert).

Answer (score 2):

if you are using php5.4 you can use traits instead of classes. It´s solve the cases witch you need the implementation of one method in two diferents classes.

Comment: if you are currently using php5.4 in a production environment, you're living on the edge. It's a RC, like it says on php.net: "THIS IS A RELEASE CANDIDATE - DO NOT USE IT IN PRODUCTION!."

Answer (score 1):

To make it type save you can define an interface for example "arraySerializable" which has the getData method. You can use this interface later in TypeHints instead of the class.

But this still doesn't give you the functionality. I suppose a common base class is not the thing you want here. So if you can't use traits you have to duplicate the code. This might be one of the rare cases where some lines duplicated code is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Make another class that only has the getData method, and make both of your existing classes extend that new class.

Comment: -1 because having a base class is messing up the inheritance chain, hampers reuse and will quickly lead to God objects and monolithic architecture.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have Traits there was an older implementation of Mixins that you could use.

You may know that:

```
<?php

class A {
    public function B() {
        var_dump($this->data);
    }
}
class X {
    protected $data;
    public function Y() {
        A::B()
    }
}

$x = new X;
$x->Y(); // will execute the code for A::B 
         // but will assume the object context
         // of $x (of class X) and will have
         // access to $this->data
         // ! this is not a static call
```

Using this principle you can create a static array of class names and/or method names that you can "mix-in" or "use" (like traits) via the magic method __get.
    ?>

Answer (score -2):

As opposed to the other answerers, I think I should comment on your design. You want to create a method that exposes all private properties of any object. An object is, in most cases, somewhat more than simply a property bag, so in what situations would you need to know *all* properties? And why do you then mark them as private?

To solve the real problem, you should take a look at public properties, or private ones with getters and setters if you want to control the incoming and outgoing data.

If you however think you need all properties of a given object (and are willing to accept "hacks" like copypaste-programming, traits and whatnot), why not simply mark them as public and call [`get_object_vars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php)?

Comment: Didn't dv but I'd assume it's some form of data mapping for which this is used. In that case yeah ether cosntruct/getData interface or public properties or reflection could be used. Not having pulic properties is a valid choice in my book though :)

Comment: @edorian If it's some kind of data access layer or template layer, deriving from a kind of TemplateObject or DAOObject containing the GetData method should be the way to go. If not, I really would like to see what OP is trying to accomplish. Returning all private properties for all objects through a single method looks to me like OP doesn't get what properties (or objects...) are for.

Comment: -1 for suggesting to add getters/setters when the OP really just wants the data in arrays. You are suggesting to widen the public API instead of keeping it small and focused. Unless the object is a Value Object, you should [avoid littering](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/GetterEradicator.html) it with [Getters and Setters](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2003/jw-0905-toolbox.html).

Comment: @CodeCaster Deriving from a DAOObject would be (or at least close to) "Active Record" and that has an extreme amount of issues associated with it (See the problems RoR or Cake has with it) and was surpassed by "Data Mapper" for most cases. But it can be valid choice, not the one that OP took it seems :)

Comment: @Gordon well yeah, the only valid answer to OP's question is either "use traits" or "copypaste it all over the place", you're right. No, wait, "use a base class that fits the purpose of the GetData method" might be a perfectly sensible solution, as well as using public properties or getters and setters, **depending on what OP wants to accomplish**. But it's struck me more than once on SO. OP asks for something not very common (which he might most probably not need, but fails to explain what he really wants), OP gets his answer, and lives on in oblivion. Well, good luck advertising that.